# Unable to install apk and launch the application in Appium docker

Tags: java, docker, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I have a docker running on linux machine with appium server on it, real device is connected via USB with all permissions granted.

[image: The devices is recognizible by adb]

The problem is when I running tests the apk is not installing, its like skipping the installation. Appium logs shows no errors. The test is running perfect locally on my Windows machine with this capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, apkLink);
```

I tried max of capabilities but it doesnt helped, so I dont know where to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is present onto your local machine , first move to some place where your driver can access your .apk file from your docker machine . In docker try running this command.

sudo docker cp /home/(name)/(folder_name)/(file_name)  (container_id):/(to_the_place_you_want_the_file_to_be)

Comment: No file isn't present anywhere, the access via link through apkLink variable. I tried your method but still couldn't install apk.

Comment: @J.Klimov :Can you give more details , if that app link is credentials protected , And can you paste folder access level , i guess it doesn't have read/write access . Check once that as well .

Comment: String apkLink = SettingsProvider.getPropertyValue("front.android.apk.link") +
                    "/" + SettingsProvider.getPropertyValue("front.android.version");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, apkLink);

This is how apk provided via link, and it isn't protected somehow